# Issue with encoding between java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD and utf8 proc in C

Tags: java, c, character-encoding

I would like to know if there are issues in handling special characters (like β) in German, Japanese ,korean languages in Java and utf8 in C.

We are using java.text.Normalizer.Form.NFD  in java side and passing the string to DB where we have custom function in C to normalize string .We have issues with names having ascents and special characters..eg : if name has ÄßÜ , after normalising DB changes it to "assu" in C function which is used to normalize.

Is this an issue with UTF8 in C or is it is a mismatch between Java and C normalizer functions.How should we handle these special characters..

Comment: What is "ust8proc" or "UTF8proc"?

Comment: It was a typo and its UTF8proc

Comment: Where does that function come from? It is not (as far as I know) in the standard C library.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Normalizer.Form.NFC or Normalizer.Form.NFKC, you can find additional informations [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html)